# How to import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.* on Groovy?

Tags: groovy, scriptom

I'm trying to run a Groovy app to manipulate Excel files on STS (by SpringSource) 2.3.0.

My Groovy version is 1.7.

Class:

```
package com.mytool

import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.ActiveXObject


/**
 * @author Mulone
 *
 */
class SurveyTool {

    static main(args) {
        print 'test'
        def wshell = new ActiveXObject('Wscript.Shell')
        wshell.popup("Scriptom is Groovy")
    }

}
```

Sadly, this is what I get:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\workspace\SurveyTool\src\com\geoadapta\surveytool\SurveyTool.groovy: 6: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.ActiveXObject
 @ line 6, column 1.
   import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.ActiveXObject
   ^

1 error
```

I also tried to rename **ActiveXObject** to **ActiveXProxy** with the same result.

I tried to import scriptom manually from the package **scriptom-all-assembly-1.6.0** but I didn't work.
Any idea?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ops, I fixed it by importing all the jar files manually and by putting **jacob-1.14.3-x86.dll** in the project folder.

Comment: What is the project folder?